# Symfony - Access Control via regex

Tags: regex, symfony

So, I'm using Symfony 2.6 (Yes, it's old, but I'm not allowed to upgrade) for a project. Currently, I got a small issue:

If the user goes to

> www.url.com/product/G

this should be allowed and he is not required to login. However, if the goes to

> www.url.com/product/GProduct

He is required to login. However, I'm unable to figure out what to do in order to tell Symfony to do exactly that.

The line in my security.yml is as the following:

```
access_control:
    - { path: /product/[^A-Z]$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

This RegEx should only match one character. However, it doesn't do what it should. I can still access `/product/GProduct` without being asked to login.

How can I achieve this? And can I achieve that at all?

Comment: I think you need to use `/product/[A-Z]$` to actually allow one uppercase letter at the end. `[^A-Z]` matches 1 character *other* than an uppercase ASCII letter.

Answer (score 1):

With :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/product/[A-Z]$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

You can match only an url with a single uppercase character.

But if you want to secure `/product/GProduct`, you have to add an other line :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/product/GProduct, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED }
    - { path: ^/product/[A-Z]$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

With static  `^/product/GProduct` or with Regex.